# VBS Script runs different when run by scheduled task vs Double Click

Tags: excel, windows, vbscript

I am trying to run the code below. When I double click the .vbs script in windows it does exactly what it needs to do. Saves and closes all open instances of excel then opens 2 sheets specified to run macros within the sheets and closes them. I use the Auto_Open in excel to sync these sheets when the computer gets in range of Wi-Fi. When I try to run the command via a .bat or directly with windows task scheduler. The first part where it needs to save and close all open excel sheets seems to not work. everything else works like a charm. Is there something basic with task scheduler I am missing? Code Below:

```
   On Error Resume Next

While Err.Number = 0

    Set objOffice = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")

    set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    objOffice.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each objWindow In objOffice.Windows

        objWindow.Activate

        Set WBook = objOffice.ActiveWorkbook

        WBook.Saved = True

            WBook.Save  

        WBook.Close

    Next

    objOffice.DisplayAlerts = True

    objOffice.Quit

    Set objOffice = Nothing

    WScript.Sleep 2000

Wend



    set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    Set objOffice = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    WScript.Sleep 2000

    objOffice.visible=True

    set WBook = objOffice.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Public\Documents\OffSide Log Storage\Ron Charawich - Offside Transmitter Log.xls",0)

    objOffice1.Run "Ron Charawich - Offside Transmitter Log.xls!Auto_Open"

       Set objOffice = Nothing  

    WScript.Sleep 30000

On Error Resume Next

While Err.Number = 0

    Set objOffice = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")

    set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    objOffice.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each objWindow In objOffice.Windows

        objWindow.Activate

        Set WBook = objOffice.ActiveWorkbook

        WBook.Saved = True

            WBook.Save  

        WBook.Close

    Next

    objOffice.DisplayAlerts = True

    objOffice.Quit

    Set objOffice = Nothing

    WScript.Sleep 2000

Wend
    set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    Set objOffice = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    WScript.Sleep 2000

    objOffice.visible=True

    set WBook = objOffice.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Tablet Sheet Storage\Nabiye_PassFail_2016_Field_Locked_Tablet.xlsm",0)

    objOffice.Run "Nabiye_PassFail_2016_Field_Locked_Tablet.xlsm!Auto_Open"

       Set objOffice = Nothing      

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: The task is probably running in a different session than the one where the Excel windows are open. When you loop through `objOffice.Windows` try to write those names or the count to a file to see what the script "sees."

Comment: If I knew the name of the excel files I wanted to close could I inject there path names anywhere?

Comment: In task scheduler you can specify the account under which a task must run, including credentials. Have you done that for this task?

Comment: I used run only when user is logged on and I have local admin privileges so I do not think it is a permissions thing.

Comment: Try calling it using cmd /c cscript filename.vbs